# My images inside the images subfolder wont show in heroku but works ok in local

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, heroku

I have a Node.Js App using express and Angular. While developing and running a local server everything worked perfectly.

But once deployed in Heroku, images (vewed in the gallery page) inside sub folders (images/*) just wont load while in Heroku.

When I try to go directly to the image URL the ones directly in the images folder work well:

```
servicentrov2.herokuapp.com/images/Fondo1.jpg
```

But the ones in subfolders wont, and show part of the page:

```
servicentrov2.herokuapp.com/images/galerias/2014Hallel/2014-Hallel-01.jpg
```

I think it might be that:
1. the sub folders are not available in server
2. some routing problem

The code is in https://github.com/blogcraft/Servicentro2.0

The Heroku app is in https://servicentrov2.herokuapp.com

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the text case wrong in the link:

`servicentrov2.herokuapp.com/images/galerias/2014Hallel/2014-Hallel-01.jpg`

should be:

`servicentrov2.herokuapp.com/images/galerias/2014hallel/2014-Hallel-01.jpg`

(Note: lowercase '2014hallel').

Comment: Bullseye! Thanks! I just didn't see that! :P

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to login to your Heroku terminal via SSH. Poke around in there and see if the images are actually located where your app is looking for them as a first step.